# Jackson Deserialize XML when an element contains HTML tags

Tags: java, spring, deserialization, jackson-databind

I am trying to deserialize an XML response using Jackson and it contains an element with string value as below:

```
<Abstract>
     <AbstractText>My Text <sup>1</sup> this. <sup>2,3</sup> and that.</AbstractText>
<Abstract>
```

I actually don't even care for this element and it would be great to IGNORE this element "Abstract" or "AbstractText" completely. But I can't find a way to ignore it.

I have two POJOs to handle this XML when it is deserialized by Jackson, and I was hoping I could either trick Jackson somehow or override it manually. But I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected END_ELEMENT, got event of type 1
```

I've tried to look for the solution but nowhere it is solved or have any workarounds. Can someone please help?

Comment: @JsonIgnore on the "Abstract" is not working ?

Comment: @PanditBiradar, no, @JsonIgnore doesn't work. After adding that annotation I am still getting the same error `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Expected END_ELEMENT, got event of type 1`.